# What is the recommended video format codec and container to play on android devices

Tags: video

I am about to encode some of my videos so that they can be played on android devices?

what is the most compatible container, codec and dimension for android devices. thanks!

Comment: You can try Handbrake (http://handbrake.fr/) for video transcoding. It supports various profiles and you can google for a configuration for a particular device. See this link I've dug up: http://www.knowyourcell.com/htc/htc-desire/desire-guides/487526/how_to_convert_videos_and_transfer_them_to_the_htc_desire.html I've used Handbrake (I have a Desire too), and the results are quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

The [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) covers this pretty thoroughly.  They have all the supported formats as well as recommendations.  I would additionally recommend using the same resolution as your screen if your device can handle it, that will much improve the quality.

Comment: ok thanks, so i am trying to encode it to h263 using ffmpeg but my phone still says: this video can not be played

Comment: @clamp What device do you have?

Comment: HTC Desire with android 2.2

Answer (score 2):

When I encode movies using Handbrake or DVDFab, I choose the "iPad" option, which create an m4v with h.264 and AAC (I think). Yes, this feels like sacrilege, but I just ignore the voices in my head. ;)

On XOOM, this plays fine. To keep the file size down, I take the audio down to stereo @ 44.1khz and 96kbps and the video rate to 1200kbps, while still maintaining 720p. This seems to work out alright and most 2 hour movies are in the 1 to 1.5GB range.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another answer on the "Optimum video codec for low end Android phones" question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27674/18559), here is what I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 \
    -sws_flags lanczos+accurate_rnd \
    -vf "scale=iw/2:-1" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -crf 23.0 \
    -preset veryslow \
    -profile:v baseline \
    -tune fastdecode \
    -strict -2 \
    output_video.mp4
```

Note that I didn't set a specific resolution, just halved the original video's via the `-vf "scale=iw/2:-1"` option which worked well for my case, but you can change that [as documented on the "Scaling (resizing) with ffmpeg" wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg).

The [H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) may also be useful.