# Cannot play .mp4 videos with the default video player

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I downloaded some .mp4 videos on my PC and I want play them on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.

Despite the .mp4 videos can be played in my PC<sup>1</sup> *(with no problem)*, in my device *(using the predefined video media player)* the video cannot be played.

This screenshot shows the videos that my device cannot play them:

[image: videos unabled to play]

Only the video *(pointed with the green arrow)* - which is the default video that my device has can be played.

When I select any of the other videos, the device says: "Content not supported":

[image: video not available]

Each time I send the video *(via cable from the PC to the device)*, it will show two options:

Do you wish convert `(insert_video_name_here.mp4)` before copy it to the device?

- Yes, convert and copy *(recommended)*.
- No, just copy *(File will copy, but it might be possible it cannot play in the device)*.

No matter which option I select, the video is not playable.

This is the information about the predefined app:

[image: app video media player]

I was reading this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26825/136494) and [this one too](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10319/136494) about similar problems, but what I understand is due the resolution of the video, but I have no idea what can I do for play these videos in my device *(despite those videos are .mp4 or .wmv files "the same as the predefined video - pointed with the green arrow in a previous screenshot")*.

I really don't want download another app and play the videos with them, hence I ask:

How can be played those videos wth the predefined app?

---

<sup>1</sup> Windows 7 Professional 32 bits. Using Google Chrome "as video player" and the Windows Media Player.

PS: I also read about software which can convert videos for device-compatibility, but I'm not sure if those are free-malware applications.

Comment: What are the resolutions of the video not played and the one that the player was able to play?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio resolution of non played video: `width: 540, height: 960`, playable video: `width: 480, height: 320`.

Comment: Are they using the same  audio and video codecs compare to the playing video? If not, try downloading a media converter for Windows, and convert the videos to use the same audio and video codecs than the playing one?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I don't know where to check if the videos are using the same codecs. I did tried convert to .mp4 and .wmv a single video using FormatFactory, but the same results ocurred: `Content not supported` *(once tried to play in the device)*.

Comment: Download MediaInfo https://mediainfo.en.uptodown.com/windows, Use it to check the differences between the 'good' and 'bad' videos then change FormatFactory parameters based in them

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you. After download MediaInfo, it seems that the differences was indeed, the codec. The playable video said: `MPEG-4: 36.9 Mib` meanwhile the other videos said `MPEG-4: (Base Media): 2.26 MiB`. Checking closely FormatFactory, there is a option called "all to mobile devices" - with different screen resolutions, and used it and it worked. Just a minor thing: when the device is vertical, the video is stretched, I have to test more, but, I can see them well in horizontal orientation. You can consider post your comment as answer and I'll upvote it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You habe 2 choices:

1. Download another media player such as VLC, MX Player, etc, then test the videos with them to know for certain if the problem is isolated to only the native video player or not. These apps are better than the phone native video player, come loaded with more codecs and can play more formats. However, you said you didn't want this solution.
2. Convert the videos to the appropriate codecs, resolutions, bit rate and other parameters recognized by the phone's video player. You will have to 'duplicate' the playing video parameters to the non-playing videos by checking the differences between them. Then, you can convert them on your PC before transferring them to the phone.